# Problem with flag weight audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

I've redacted the name of the user in question, but as far as I have seen they've been an upstanding and productive member of the community, which made me mildly surprised to see that they have a flag weight of 75 ([the default is 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight)). I decided to investigate how that came to be, and looking at their flagging history (as moderators are able to do, in addition to the user themself), I see nothing:

[image]

Even flags on posts that were deleted should appear on this page, so I don't understand how this is possible. I looked at a few other randomly selected, moderately active users, and none of them have an incorrectly low flag weight, so it would seem that this is localized to this one user. Of course, I will provide the name of the user to the SE team (so they can take a look at the page themselves), and I'd be happy to do so in public if the consensus is that this is not a big deal; I just thought it'd be better to err on the side of privacy first.

---

By the way, while doing this I noticed that the flag weight audit page always reads "Your flagging history", even when it is not the user themself viewing the page. Obviously a very minor point, since the only people who can look at a user's flag weight audit other than the user themself are the moderators, but I decided to [raise it on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115932/minor-correction-for-flag-weight-audit-page).

Comment: A not very well educated guess: Comment flags do not show up in the flag history.  They [stopped having comment flags count toward flag weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100033/why-didnt-flagging-comments-affect-my-flagging-summary-or-flag-weight) but perhaps didn't take away the effects to flag weight from before this change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jonas Meyer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1424/jonas-meyer) has the right of it. Comment flags have actually *never* been shown in the flag report (among other things, any valid comment flags would not be possible to show because we do not retain visible traces for normal users to see deleted comments like we do deleted posts). However, at the beginning, they *did* affect flag weight by half the amount - +5 for a valid, -5 for an invalid.

Unlike reputation, flag weight is simply calculated as an operation performed on the current value. We lack any form of state history for the flag weight value, and with it the ability to track exact sources of the change. As a consequence, there are some users who have positive or negative flag weight changes from comment flags that are retained from when that period occurred.

The user in question has, apparently, had -25 net result from comment flags prior to the flag weight changes.

Answer (score 1):

Flag weight is now dead, with it many of these requests.

It was just way too hard to explain. See: [What happened to flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight)